# Change select options on onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i do here is that when i select any option in a selectbox it automatically changes the option in another selectbox.But i want to change the options as soon as the page loads in my case it changes after clicking on the option.

HTML:

```
<select name="ref_type_selectbox" id="ref_type_selectbox" class="selectbox_two" accesskey="t">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Numbered item</option>
<option value="2">Heading</option>
<option value="3">Footnote</option>
<option value="4">Endnote</option>
<option value="5">Equation</option>
</select>

<select name="ref_to_selectbox" id="ref_to_selectbox" class="reference_to_selectbox" accesskey="r">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Page number</option>
<option value="1">Paragraph number(no content)</option>
<option value="1">Paragraph number(full content)</option>
<option value="1">Paragraph Text</option>
<option value="1">Above/Below</option>
<option value="2">Heading Text</option>
<option value="2">Heading number(no content)</option>
<option value="2">Heading number(full content)</option>
<option value="2">Above/Below</option>
<option value="3">Footnote number</option>
<option value="3">Above/Below</option>
<option value="3">Footnote number(formatted)</option>
<option value="4">Endnote number</option>
<option value="4">Above/Below</option>
<option value="4">Endnote number(formatted)</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#ref_type_selectbox").change(function() 
{
if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
$(this).data('options', $('#ref_to_selectbox option').clone());
}
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
$('#ref_to_selectbox').html(options);
});
```

Comment: onload how you are going to decide which option need to be selected?

Comment: The same values should only be selected.

Comment: still your not answering to @AlivetoDie comment .read it twice .

Comment: I didn't get you i need first option selected(Numbered item) and options related to that in second selectbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After binding to `change` event trigger the event itself:

```
$("#ref_type_selectbox").change();
```

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ref_type_selectbox").change(function() 
  {
  if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
  $(this).data('options', $('#ref_to_selectbox option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#ref_to_selectbox').html(options);
  });
  
  $("#ref_type_selectbox").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ref_type_selectbox" id="ref_type_selectbox" class="selectbox_two" accesskey="t">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Numbered item</option>
<option value="2">Heading</option>
<option value="3">Footnote</option>
<option value="4">Endnote</option>
<option value="5">Equation</option>
</select>

<select name="ref_to_selectbox" id="ref_to_selectbox" class="reference_to_selectbox" accesskey="r">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Page number</option>
<option value="1">Paragraph number(no content)</option>
<option value="1">Paragraph number(full content)</option>
<option value="1">Paragraph Text</option>
<option value="1">Above/Below</option>
<option value="2">Heading Text</option>
<option value="2">Heading number(no content)</option>
<option value="2">Heading number(full content)</option>
<option value="2">Above/Below</option>
<option value="3">Footnote number</option>
<option value="3">Above/Below</option>
<option value="3">Footnote number(formatted)</option>
<option value="4">Endnote number</option>
<option value="4">Above/Below</option>
<option value="4">Endnote number(formatted)</option>
</select>
```

P.S: Keeping values in JS array will make it more efficient

Comment: Basically i just copy the code from stackoverflow so can you please explain that what i'm doing in this.Don't know how clone and filter works.